# Fixed: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus') when using mui autocomplete react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use *mui's* autocomplete in my *SearchBar* but when I click on the search bar to search something it throws this error:
**ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')**.

I'm not sure why it does it and when I searched no answer was applicable to my case, so if someone knows what the problem is I would really appreciate the help.

This is my *SearchBar* component:

```
const SearchBar = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const { data, isPending, error } = useSearchSubredditSuggestions(searchQuery);

 /... code that returns a list of suggestions .../

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" spacing={0}>
      <Search>
        <SearchIconWrapper>
          <SearchIcon />
        </SearchIconWrapper>
        <Autocomplete
          options={data || []}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => `r/${option}`}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <StyledInputBase
              {...params.InputProps}
              inputRef={inputRef}
              onChange={handleChangedSearchBar}
              placeholder="Search…"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
            />
          )}
          loading={isPending}
          renderOption={(props, option) => (
            <MenuItem
              {...props}
              onClick={() => handleListItemClick(option)}
            >
              {`r/${option}`}
            </MenuItem>
          )}
        />
      </Search>
      {isPending && <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />}
      {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

I tried to change the inputRef in line 88 (I'm pretty sure that's the cause of the error) to what I pasted above (this is the original:

```
inputRef={(input) => {
    params.InputProps.ref(input);
    inputRef.current = input;
}}
```

and I tried updating the *mui* module cause I saw that it's maybe because of that but it didn't help.

I expect being able to search and show the suggestions in the autocomplete without having an error.

## ***UPDATE fixed:***

I tried starting from scratch, using the mui example that works and building upon it, the selution is wierd but simple: the InputBase didn't work for some reason in the autocomplete module, I simply changed it to TextField and the issue resolved. here is the updated working SearchBar:

```
return (
<Stack direction="row"
justifyContent="center"
alignItems="center"
spacing={0}>
  <Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    id="searchBar"
    disableClearable
    options={data}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => `r/${option}`}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <Search>
      <SearchIconWrapper>
        <SearchIcon />
      </SearchIconWrapper>
      **<StyledTextField
        {...params}
        placeholder="Search subreddit"
        InputProps={{
          ...params.InputProps,
          type: 'search',
        }}
        onChange={handleChangedSearchBar}
      />**
    </Search>
    )}
    onChange={(event, value) => handleListItemClick(value)}
  />
  <StyledFormControl>
    <NativeSelect
      defaultValue={"new"}
      inputProps={{
        name: "listing",
        id: "listing-options",
      }}
      onChange={(event) => {setSelectedListing(event.target.value)}}
    >
      {listings.map((val: string) => {
        return <option value={val}>{val}</option>;
      })}
    </NativeSelect>
  </StyledFormControl>
</Stack>
```

);

Comment: Try console logging `data` and make sure it is returning an array , and since you are suspecting inputRef might be causing problems , try commenting that part see if it works.

Comment: it doesnt get to this part, the moment i click on the searchbar the error is thrown. after commenting that part it still doesnt work but there isnt any other thing i can see that will cause the error

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducible code in codesandbox ? It will be easier to help.

Comment: fixed the problem. for anyone wondering, for some reason you can't use InputBase for the auto complete module in mui, the problem was with this line: inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}"

to fix it I simply changed the styledInputBase to a textField and it worked